# Calculate the force of interaction of objects in UE

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I want to calculate the force of the collision. For example, the car is on the bridge, and I want to find
pressure force. In the second case, I have a falling car, and I want to find the force of the impact. Are there any functions for this?

I want to use c ++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you do is multiply the Mass and the Speed together

```
void AMyActor::OnHit(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComp, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, FVector NormalImpulse, const FHitResult& Hit)
{
   float HitForce = OtherActor->GetVelocity.Size() * OtherComp->GetMass();
   UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT(HitForce));
}
```

HitForce is the variable you're looking for.